# SaveChanges() is saving Unchanged records

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I don't know if I'm missing something... anyway:

[image: image 1]

You can see, for example, that the object with the property 'HomeTeam' = ' Forest Green Rovers' has the state = 'Unchanged'. Anyway all entities are 'unchanged' in my case. So, if I'm correct, the saveChanges shouldn't try to insert those in my table but that's what it's happening:

[image: image 2]

The primary key has been violated, but EF shouldn't have tried to add this record (the one with the property HomeTeam = 'Forest Green Rovers') since it's  'Unchanged', right?

Why is EF doing that?

The entity:

```
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class MatchInfo
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MatchInfo()
    {
        this.Sport = "Soccer";
        this.OddsInfoes1X2 = new HashSet<OddsInfo1X2>();
        this.Odds1X2Movements = new HashSet<OddsMovement>();
        this.OddsInfoOverUnders = new HashSet<OddsInfoOverUnder>();
        this.OddsMovementOverUnders = new HashSet<OddsMovementOverUnder>();
        this.HistoryResults = new HashSet<HistoryResult>();
    }

    public string League { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public string AwayTeam { get; set; }
    public string FinalScore { get; set; }
    public string Sport { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OddsInfo1X2> OddsInfoes1X2 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OddsMovement> Odds1X2Movements { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OddsInfoOverUnder> OddsInfoOverUnders { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OddsMovementOverUnder> OddsMovementOverUnders { get; set; }
    public virtual TeamsStatFinal TeamsStatFinal { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<HistoryResult> HistoryResults { get; set; }
}
```

}

More Info:

```
foreach (something){
     /*iterating on a web page and where I build the object oMatchInfo */
     if (oMatchInfo != null)
     {
          oMatchInfoTemp = (from m in context.MatchInfoes where m.HomeTeam == oMatchInfo.HomeTeam && m.AwayTeam == oMatchInfo.AwayTeam && m.Date == oMatchInfo.Date select m).FirstOrDefault<MatchInfo>();
          if (oMatchInfoTemp == null)
          {
              context.MatchInfoes.Add(oMatchInfo);
          }
          else
          {                                         
              context.OddsInfoes1X2.AddRange(oMatchInfo.OddsInfoes1X2);
          }
     }

}
/* here there is the context.saveChanges() - the context is the same */
```

ops. I have found my error and it's really stupid :-( in a related function inside the for there was some uncommented code where I was adding entities without checking the PK constraints. 
The state 'Unchanged' (first image) confused me and I have kept focusing on that...
Sorry :-)

Comment: is that all the code? could you include the class as well for the enitity

Comment: Please add the other `partial class MatchInfo` which defined the keys. your issue is `Edit: That's the part where I check the primary key before adding in the context:` in that section please add where that is called.

Comment: Like i said add! where you are calling `if (oMatchInfo != null)
{` Code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still can not tell from your code, as your not showing enough.

You need to include a lot more code for us to understand why you are calling what you are.

I hope this code help you understand, this is not a solution for you, I'm just trying to show that your for-each doesn't look right, depending on what you are doing when, but as you are not showing all the code we cant tell.

```
  public void Save(TEntity entity) //change this to your entity
    {
        if(entity == null)
            return;

        //change this to your key, this is the identifier for new
        if (entity.Id == 0) 
        {
            entity.CreateOnDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }


        Context.SaveChanges(); //this may not suit your design
    }
```

Comment: This is solving your problem but is far away from the practice that is causing the issue. Come back to this error in the future and a clearer mind to inspect the code once more.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add entities to the context that are *not new entities* (the PK already exists in the database) then you need to Attach the entity rather than Add it.

More details here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx

To elaborate, look through the context contents carefully. You will find an entity that has the Added state.

Comment: i dont think this is addressing the issue. He doesn't want to add. hes loop through existing records. he is leaving there state as is, ie they are not new or in state added. `NvM!!!!!! he added more code!`

Comment: @Seabizkit we shall see. There is a composite PK here that may be complicating issues.

Comment: he added the relevant code on which your comment was based after the fact.. so your answer made way more sense, but only after hes added the important bits

Comment: @Seabizkit yeh I took a wild stab at what the root problem was as it seems all too very familiar

Answer (score 3):

You're adding an existing entry to the database.

```
if (oMatchInfo != null)
{
    oMatchInfoTemp = (from m in context.MatchInfoes where m.HomeTeam == 
    oMatchInfo.HomeTeam && m.AwayTeam == oMatchInfo.AwayTeam && m.Date == 
    oMatchInfo.Date select m).FirstOrDefault<MatchInfo>();

    if (oMatchInfoTemp == null)
    {
        context.MatchInfoes.Add(oMatchInfo);
    }
    else
    {                                         
        context.OddsInfoes1X2.AddRange(oMatchInfo.OddsInfoes1X2);
    }
}
```

This way you're adding a model that has an ID which matches the entry in the database, therefore your database is giving the `cannot insert duplicate key` error.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here:

```
if (oMatchInfo != null)
{
     oMatchInfoTemp = (from m in context.MatchInfoes where m.HomeTeam == oMatchInfo.HomeTeam && m.AwayTeam == oMatchInfo.AwayTeam && m.Date == oMatchInfo.Date select m).FirstOrDefault<MatchInfo>();
     if (oMatchInfoTemp == null)
     {
         context.MatchInfoes.Add(oMatchInfo);
     }
     else
     {
         // CODE SMELL                                         
         context.OddsInfoes1X2.AddRange(oMatchInfo.OddsInfoes1X2);
     }
 }
```

In the else case you are re-adding a lot of entities that were already inserted into the database and this is what is re-linking your current match for insertion.

Maybe you want to insert the diff between the existing X2 and the new. The typical code will look like:

```
context.OddsInfoes1X2.AddRange(oMatchInfo.OddsInfoes1X2.Where(t => !oMatchInfoTemp.OddsInfoes1X2.Contains(t)))
```

What are you trying to do in the else statement?

Hope this help!

Comment: Agreed, this `if` block needs justification

Comment: I was investigating on that code but if I comment the above line I still get the same error (the else statement I mean). Anyway what I'm trying to do it's adding in the database another entity related to the first.

Comment: Who is creating oMatchInfo variable?